# Hashing with linear probing

Tags: java, beginner, hash-map

I am seeking a review of a previous project I completed to help understand hash tables. 
 The following is my implementation of a **hash-table using linear probing.**

My solution assumes a number of variables have been initialised:

- Private int[] H;  *Representing the hash table with each value initialised to -1*
- private int hSize; *Storing the size of the hash table*

**Hash Function:**

```
public int hash(int key){
    return key % hSize;
}
```

**Add value to hash table:**

```
private void addToHash(int value){

    int i;

    for (i = hash(value); H[i] != -1; i = (i + 1) % H.length)
        if (H[i] == value) return;

    H[i] = value;

}
```

**Search for value:**

```
public int hashSearch(int key){

    int hash = hash(key);

    for (int i = hash; H[i] != -1; i = (i + 1) % H.length)
        if (H[i] == key) return i; 

    return -1;

}
```

I am looking for feedback regarding the design of my solution / programming style - Anything which could be improved in the future or would not be encouraged when programming in the industry.

Comment: I think this question could benefit from including the complete class rather than a subset of its operations as shown by kraskevich's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The method names are a little bit misleading. They're already in the `HashTable` class, aren't they? If yes, then why would you add the `hash` word to their names (except for the one that actually computes the hash)? `hashSearch` and `addToHash` make it sound like the code looks for/adds a hash. It doesn't. It adds/searches for the value.
2. What does the `hashSearch` return? The index is the internal implementation detail. I do not see a good reason to expose it to the client. It should probably return a `boolean` value (and I'd call it something like `contains`).
3. You did not present the full code, so there are a lot of questions left. What is the initial number of buckets in the table? Does it grow? What happens if it gets fully loaded (the `addToHash` method can stuck in an infinity loop in that case)? These questions are very important, but, unfortunately, I can't comment on those as the relevant parts of your code are missing.